# Joomla Integration with objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, joomla

I am developing an iPhone app for a joomla site. But I am confused with integrating my native iphone app with joomla. I need to implement registration and log in functionality in my app as in joomla website. Is there any SDK or pluggin available for doing the same? Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for webservice.

Comment: check this it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065455/jfactory-failing-to-import/19065548#19065548

Comment: @ Jitendra : Am looking for ios sdk or lib files for connecting joomla site by using native objective c codes

Comment: I fear, this isn't an Objective-C nor iphone nor iOS question. Rather related to PHP and Joomla. Once you have implemented the web service API - or can point to the documentation, then it may become an iOS related question (how to make network requests) which then however is totally orthogonal to how the web service is implemented.